# How i can set custom animation between slide in CarouselSlider flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, carousel-slider

I have created an image slider using `CarouselSlider`, I want to set animation when the page change but when the page change it will not reflect to the dot indicator

slider and dot position

[image: slider and dot position]

here is the full code of my slider

```
  final RxInt _current = 0.obs;
  PageController pageViewController = PageController();
  final CarouselController _controller = CarouselController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      for (var imageUrl in images) {
        precacheImage(NetworkImage(imageUrl), context);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Slider demo')),
      body: Obx(
        () => Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              bottom: 40.0,
              left: 0.0,
              right: 0.0,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    AnimatedSmoothIndicator(
                      activeIndex: _current.value,
                      count: images.length,
                      effect: ExpandingDotsEffect(
                        radius: 10,
                        dotWidth: 10,
                        dotHeight: 10,
                        activeDotColor: Colors.green,
                        expansionFactor: 4,
                        dotColor: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.17),
                      ), // your preferred effect
                      onDotClicked: (index) {
                        pageViewController.animateToPage(
                          index,
                          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                          curve: Curves.ease,
                        );
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
              child: Expanded(
                child: Container(
                    child: CarouselSlider.builder(
                  itemCount: images.length,
                  carouselController: _controller,
                  options: CarouselOptions(
                    autoPlay: true,
                    aspectRatio: 14 / 8.5,
                    viewportFraction: 0.8,
                    enlargeCenterPage: true,
                    autoPlayAnimationDuration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                    autoPlayInterval: const Duration(seconds: 4),
                    autoPlayCurve: Curves.easeInOutSine,
                    onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                      _current.value = index;
                    },
                    scrollPhysics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index, realIdx) {
                    return index == _current.value
                        ? ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                            child: Stack(
                              children: [
                                Image.network(
                                  images[index],
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  width: 1000,
                                  height: 170,
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        : Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
                            child: Container(
                              child: ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                                child: Stack(
                                  children: [
                                    Image.network(
                                      images[index],
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      width: 1000,
                                      height: 172,
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                  },
                )),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet ?

Comment: yeah ! sure i update my question